# AspNet.Core Identity Authentification from WPF client

Tags: wpf, authentication, asp.net-core, identity

I've implemented asp.net core Identity authentifaiction and it's working fine with my web application. In the startup.cs file, I have the following:

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings  
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

And in the Login.chtml.cs, I've the the login method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {                       

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //...
            }
            else
            {
               //....
            }                
        }

        return Page();
    }
```

Now I'm putting in place a WPF client in which I want to authenticate my users using the AspNetCore.Identity login procedure. Any suggestion about how to proceed will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you use WPF why not use Windows authentication? The OS already knows who the domain user is

Comment: In fact, the WPF client will be used by customers who are not necessarily in a domain.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I decided to go with [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/) in order to have a centralized login and workflow for the WPF client and other clients that I may need later.